# ASP.NET Web App creation to retrieve and display from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, telerik

I'm trying to create a very simple web type app in ASP.NET C# that will allow a user to input there 3 digit ID into a box, it will then return there name in a separate box from the data stored in SQL.

After this step is completed id like them to input a start time and end time they've been on a job for and then have an auto calculation and display to them how long its taken in hours and minutes.

Finally after they've ticked a box to say if they've worked through there 30 min lunch break they would input a job number and it will then write it back to a sql database via a stored procedure.

Where on earth would I start?

Ive tried some Telerik controls and basic ASP.NET boxes bound to the datasource but cannot get anything returned on screen (Although the results return when running through the test connection wizard to SQL)

Comment: Unfortunately SO isn't a place for tutorials. You must start with [What you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and then come back with specific issues you run into. You can Google or Bing tutorials all over the web about doing CRUD operations in ASP.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start hear

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp

and then maybe move on to to

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh341490.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532866(v=vs.100).aspx

when you have a better understanding,

Comment: Thanks for the posts gents, my issue is not knowing where to start with this so thanks for the pointers, ill have a further look into it